# Rufus settings default settings confusing

Tags: rufus

Rufus default settings

UEFI only: Partition scheme: GPT Target system: UEFI (non CSM) File system: FAT32

Legacy BIOS only: Partition scheme: MBR Target system: BIOS (or UEFI-CSM) File system: NTFS

if using NTFS file system on GPT/ UEFI mode . Is there any harm and what does it affect? What about when installing Windows to GPT/ UEFI system.?

Whether Fat32 must always be used in GPT/ UEFI mode?

i tested acronis TI ISO to usb boot with Rufus and it seems to work fine. With ( NTFS file system and GPT/ UEFI )

PS. I know this is a silly question, but is it possible to burn a CD in GPT/UEFI MODE in some software?

Comment: AFAIK, EFI partition is always FAT32 since UEFI firmware always includes a FAT32 driver, but not an NTFS driver _(e.g. w/o an NTFS driver, UEFI firmware can't hand off to the EFI bootloader on a partition it can't recognize)_. EFI boot requires a GPT partition table _(MBR can't be used for the boot drive, but can for other partitions)_, whereas BIOS requires an MBR partition table and doesn't recognize GPT at all. CDs/DVDs don't use filesystems drives use, so in the way that question is asked, no; however, CDs/DVDs will EFI boot if those files are contained within the correct folder structure.

Comment: @JW0914 MBR can certainly be used for the boot drive on UEFI systems (the specification says that's for "removable devices" but doesn't explicitly exclude non-removable ones), while most BIOS systems don't recognize _any_ partition table, MBR or not (they only care about the bootcode next to it); there are exceptions but in general all four combinations are "standards compliant".

Comment: @u1686_grawity A GPT boot drive cannot be used with BIOS - it's simply [not possible](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/windows-and-gpt-faq#can-windows-vista--windows-server-2008--and-later-read--write--and-boot-from-gpt-disks) with Windows.  _(I wasn't aware MBR could be used on the boot drive with UEFI, thank you for letting me know =])_

Comment: @JW0914: Yeah, but that's more like *Windows* requires a MBR partition table when booting from BIOS; the BIOS itself still doesn't. (Well, unless it's e.g. from the era where the BIOS took care of hibernation into a special partition, like old laptops.) Syslinux for example includes MBR bootcode that can read GPT partition tables, while GRUB's bootcode doesn't use the partition table either way... The BIOS might check for the "boot signature" but it's fine with the MBR having only the GPT Protective Partition.

Answer (score 4):

> Whether Fat32 must always be used in GPT/ UEFI mode?

FAT32 is the **baseline** that all UEFI implementations are required to support at minimum. They may support more filesystem types (e.g. it's said that many support NTFS), but unless you know for sure that you'll be using the USB stick on mainboards that support the other filesystem, it's best to stick with FAT32 for the initial jump.

But once the firmware finds your initial loader in the FAT32 filesystem, that program can then load its own filesystem drivers (either UEFI-level as Rufus does, or internal to the bootloader as GRUB does) and access files from whatever filesystem type it wants.

So as far as I know, choosing "GPT/UEFI + NTFS" in Rufus still gives you a *small* FAT32 partition that only loads the `UEFI:NTFS` driver and jumps to the main NTFS partition, which contains the rest.

(Actually, the version of Rufus I downloaded doesn't seem to offer FAT32 at all if I choose UEFI – only NTFS; I don't remember if the "pure FAT32" option was removed at some point? The problem with FAT32 when creating Windows installers, at least, is that it requires you to split the oversized "Install.wim" file – which really is not a big deal, you can do it with dism.exe – but I recall the Rufus developer rather did not like that approach.)

> if using NTFS file system on GPT/ UEFI mode . Is there any harm and what does it affect? What about when installing Windows to GPT/ UEFI system.?

This mode involves the loading of an external driver (not signed by the same developers as the rest of the OS) when the USB stick boots, so it might will not work if you want the entire installation process to strictly conform to Secure Boot from start to end – e.g. if you have Secure Boot enabled with the strictest "Windows only, no third-party stuff" mode, then it will fail to load the NTFS driver that Rufus brings.

> PS. I know this is a silly question, but is it possible to burn a CD in GPT/UEFI MODE in some software?

Well, that's how the original ISO was made to begin with. An `.iso` image is **literally** a CD image, so you don't even need to transform it in any way – it's already prepared for burning into a CD or DVD, and in most cases nowadays (for both Windows and Linux ISOs) they are both BIOS- and UEFI-bootable.

If you were burning your own CDs (or creating ISOs; same thing) using something like `mkisofs`, you'd need to specify the right options for "[El Torito](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/312789/making-a-uefi-bootable-image-with-mkisofs-and-eltorito-boot-efiboot-img)" boot. (CDs do not use plain GPT or MBR, in general – the El Torito boot format is a bit more complex – though I think an emulated MBR and/or a "EFI System Partition" is still in there somewhere.)

Comment: It should be pointed out that _"Secure Boot enabled with the strictest "Windows only, no third-party stuff" mode"_ is a __restriction__ you will find on Microsoft produced devices only, as other manufacturers are smart enough not to give to too much credence about needing 2 different Secure Boot modes, especially after Microsoft have been [caught with their pants down](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2023/03/unkillable-uefi-malware-bypassing-secure-boot-enabled-by-unpatchable-windows-flaw/) about their more restrictive version of Secure Boot being "safer" than the regular one...

Comment: ...and are currently in the process of [revoking pretty much all their existing "Microsoft enhanced" Secure Boot signed Windows UEFI bootloaders](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb5025885-how-to-manage-the-windows-boot-manager-revocations-for-secure-boot-changes-associated-with-cve-2023-24932-41a975df-beb2-40c1-99a3-b3ff139f832d).

As to the reason why Rufus does not prefer to split large files it is because it is very costly in time for the user whereas, provided the Secure Boot signing entity doesn't __abuse__ their particular position, a mere 1:1 copy can do.

Comment: No, I was talking about the opt-in mode that you will find on _various_ devices; certainly MS-oriented, as HP seems to enable this as part of "Device Guard compliance" mode, but it's been seen in Gigabyte and ASUS firmwares as well.

Comment: I am talking about that mode too. But your point is interesting because the only place I ever saw that dual Secure Boot choice was on Microsoft devices (Surface, 2023 ARM Dev Kit) as well as in Microsoft's Hyper-V. At any rate my point that the _BlackLotus_ fiasco is proof (if one was needed) that using the more restrictive version of Secure Boot will not actually make your device more secure, still stands, and there really was no valid reason for Microsoft, especially as the Secure Boot signing vetting entity, to split Secure Boot into a Microsoft and non Microsoft version.

Comment: All in all, this dual Secure Boot mode is a bit too convenient a way to prevent non Microsoft OSes from being installed on a system when the user has no idea what's going on, because this effectively locks Linux out too (and not just the NTFS driver and bootloader used by Rufus). Thus, it strongly looks like Microsoft has a major conflict of interest here, and that their decision to introduce a "regular" and "platinum" version of Secure Boot was based mostly on what would benefit them rather than the end user.

Comment: Creating WinPE ISOs must be done on Windows, requiring utilities contained within the ADK to create a WinPE bootable ISO, since doing so requires [`oscdimg`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/oscdimg-command-line-options), but if used directly, the command becomes rather complicated; instead, the ADK script `MakeWinPeMedia` can be called by opening the ADK environment in a terminal: `Cmd /k "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Deployment Tools\DandISetEnv.bat"`, then `MakeWinPeMedia /ISO <workingDirectory> <destination>`

Comment: Regarding `install.<esd|wim>` sizes: Unless choosing a multi version/multi language installer, the `install.<esd|wim>` is _always_ <4GB _(usually ~3.8GB)_. Normally, install ISOs use an `install.esd` since the ESD compression ratio is ~33% more efficient than WIM's. and even ones containing Home, Education, and Pro are ~3.8GB _([example](https://i.imgur.com/pt6MWb9.png))_

Comment: @JW0914: Not the ones we download from VLSC – the whole .iso image is ~5.5 GB and the Sources\Install.wim (with Pro/Enterprise/Education/ProEdu; no Home) is ~4.8 GB.

Comment: @u1686_grawity I wasn't aware of that =] It's likely in WIM form for deployment purposes since deploying Windows trough MEM/SCCM/MDT requires a WIM _(as does WSIM to create an answer file)_. If not deploying, the WIM simply needs to be exported to ESD, which will drop it below 4GB: **(1)** Get image index for the version being installed: `Dism /Get-ImageInfo /ImageFile:"Path/to/install.wim"` | **(2)** Export Index # from #1 to ESD: `dism /Export-Image /SourceImageFile:"Path/to/install.wim" /SourceIndex:<#> /DestinationImageFile:"Path/to/install.esd" /Compress:Recovery /CheckIntegrity`

Answer (score 0):

Using the NTFS file system on a GPT/UEFI system does not cause any harm. In fact, it can offer some advantages over the FAT32 file system. Here are some points to consider:

Advantages of using NTFS on a GPT/UEFI system:

1. Larger partition sizes: NTFS supports larger partition sizes compared to FAT32, allowing you to create larger storage volumes.
2. File and folder permissions: NTFS provides more advanced file and folder permissions, allowing for more granular control over access rights and security.
3. Compression and encryption: NTFS supports file compression and encryption, which can be useful for saving disk space or protecting sensitive data.
4. Journaling: NTFS uses a journaling system that helps maintain the integrity of the file system, reducing the risk of data corruption in case of unexpected power loss or system crashes.

When installing Windows on a GPT/UEFI system, you can choose either the NTFS or FAT32 file system. The selection depends on your specific requirements and the capabilities of your system. Windows installations typically use NTFS by default because of its advanced features.

It is not necessary to use FAT32 exclusively in GPT/UEFI mode. While FAT32 is compatible with both UEFI and legacy BIOS systems, NTFS is also supported in UEFI mode and offers additional benefits. However, FAT32 can still be useful in certain scenarios, such as when creating a bootable USB drive for firmware updates or older systems that do not support NTFS.

Regarding burning a CD in GPT/UEFI mode, it is not possible to create a GPT partition scheme on a CD as CDs typically use the ISO 9660 file system. GPT is typically used with larger storage devices like hard drives and SSDs. However, you can burn an ISO file to a CD using software like Rufus or other CD burning tools. The ISO file can contain the necessary files for booting in UEFI mode, even if the CD itself does not use the GPT partition scheme.